# An app put made my Status Bar auto-hide and transparent. How to fix? (Nova, System UI)

Tags: 8.1-oreo, nexus

What I've tried: uninstall the app (Black Pocket) and restart.

Also tried: Google. All search results tell me how to hide the status bar, which is not what I want.

Obviously like most users I want to see all the battery and connectivity icons when I press the power button, then the Home button.

Using Nova and System UI on Android 8.1.0 on a Nexus 6P - as if this would have anything to do with it, when I saw the status bar go transparent and auto-hide upon install of the app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open Nova Settings.
2. Click on Look & feel.
3. Enable Show notification bar.